# I'm thinking of a name

Tags: riddle, word

I'm thinking of a name...

> I'm seen in the middle - though I finish later
>   
> Split and I could be an agreement from a Vater
>   
> I'm 5/12 in a calendar
>   
> Split again and I'm a different nickname with a preposition

What is the name?

HINT:

> The 5/12 isn't a date

Comment: NOTE: OP's profile lists home country as England.  So if you're translating 5/12 as a date, it's Dec. 5, not May 12.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore don't worry - that clue isn't a date. (**BIG HINT**)

Comment: Oughtn't it be Summer?

Comment: @feelinferrety well it was close enough

Comment: Or Winter, in the southern hemisphere. Associating months with seasons is bad :/

Comment: How about just "middle"?

Comment: @feelinferrety yeah thats good

Comment: Could you change "calendar" to "calendater" so it rhymes?

Comment: @xdhmoore I don't think I can just make up words :)

Comment: @Beastly\ Gerbil ...do it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> JASON

I'm seen in the middle - though I finish later

> In calendar, month July to November spell JASON. So starts in the middle of the year, but finishes 5 months later.

Split and I could be an agreement from a Vater

> JA is yes in German, and SON

5/12 in Calendar

> jfmamj-JASON-d - the first letters of the 12 months have jason in it

different nickname with a preposition

> JAS nickname for James and the preposition in ON

Comment: I'm convinced..

Comment: Last clue could be SON?

Comment: I think JAS  (Jayce) is a BRO-ish nickname for Jason.

Comment: Correct! I'll give you some help to finish. When in the calendar is the first letter July, and where does N come, after or later? And for the last one, you have 'ON' so what does the remaining letters spell?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore it can also be for 'James'

Comment: Oh yes and with the Vater one - it would be 'Ja Son' which means 'yes son'

Comment: Umm.  N is still autumn.  Your original wording was correct.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil thanks...i'll edit the answer and complete it.

Comment: Something wrong here.  While I agree that the answer is correct, July is summer, and November is still Autumn.   Even if we go Southern Hemisphere, then the start is winter and the end is spring.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore because of the dimorphism of the seasons in the two hemispheres I'll change it to 'middle'. That works for both hemispheres

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> May?

I'm seen in Autumn - though I finish later

> May

Split and I could be an agreement from a Vater

> Ay

I'm 5/12 in a calendar

> May

Split again and I'm a different name with a preposition

> Ma

Comment: This only works in the southern hemisphere

Comment: Sorry  no, none of them are right

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> St Nicholas

I'm seen in Autumn - though I finish later

> St. Nicholas eve is Dec. 5, still autumn, but he finishes up on Dec. 24th.

Split and I could be an agreement from a Vater

> All I'm getting is the German reference.

I'm 5/12 in a calendar

> St. Nicholas eve.

Split again and I'm a different nickname with a preposition

> No clue.  Lets play around with different names of Santa.

Comment: Nope sorry, not quite